# Highcharts tooltip showing selected points

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts, drilldown

I allowed multiple selection while clicking (first click selects a chart and second click performs a drilldown on that chart). I want to show a tooltip (or any other way) that displays all selected charts (i.e: if I select two charts I want a tooltip showing information about this two charts).

Here my HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Highcharts</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
        <script src="http://github.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
        <script src="highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!--Black theme
        <script src="black-theme.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
        <!-- <button id="button">Get selected points</button>
         <div>event: <span id="label"></span></div>-->
    </body>
</html>
```

And here my Javascript file:

```
$(function () {
    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            events: {
                drilldown: function (e) {
                    if (!e.seriesOptions && e.point.selected) {
                        var chart = this,
                                points = chart.getSelectedPoints(),
                                drilldowns = {
                                    'Animals': {
                                        name: 'Animals',
                                        data: [
                                            ['Cows', 2],
                                            ['Sheep', 3]
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    'Fruits': {
                                        name: 'Fruits',
                                        data: [
                                            ['Apples', 5],
                                            ['Oranges', 7],
                                            ['Bananas', 2]
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    'Cars': {
                                        name: 'Cars',
                                        data: [
                                            ['Toyota', 1],
                                            ['Volkswagen', 2],
                                            ['Opel', 5]
                                        ]
                                    }
                                };

                        Highcharts.each(points, function (p) {
                            chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(p, drilldowns[p.name]);
                        });
                        chart.applyDrilldown();
                    }

                },
                drillup: function (e) {
                    var chart = this,
                            points = [];
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        points = chart.getSelectedPoints();

                        Highcharts.each(points, function (p) {
                            // unselect points from previous drilldown
                            p.selected = false;
                            p.setState('', true);
                        });
                    }, 0);
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Async drilldown'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            categories: [
                'Animals',
                'Fruits',
                'Cars'
            ],
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Values'
            }

        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                    '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f}</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: false,
            useHTML: true
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                allowPointSelect: true
            },
            series: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
                allowPointSelect: true,
                name: 'Test things',
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: [{
                        name: 'Animals',
                        y: 5,
                        drilldown: true
                    }, {
                        name: 'Fruits',
                        y: 2,
                        drilldown: true
                    }, {
                        name: 'Cars',
                        y: 4,
                        drilldown: true
                    }]
            }],
        drilldown: {
            series: []
        }
    });
});
```

Edit: I've tried this solution, but unfortunetely only shows the last point selected:

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        allowPointSelect: true
    },
    series: {
        borderWidth: 0,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
        },
        point: {
            events: {
                select: function () {
                    var text = this.category + ': ' + this.y + ' was last selected',
                            chart = this.series.chart;
                    if (!chart.lbl) {
                        chart.lbl = chart.renderer.label(text, 100, 70)
                                .attr({
                                    padding: 10,
                                    r: 5,
                                    fill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
                                    zIndex: 5
                                })
                                .css({
                                    color: '#FFFFFF'
                                })
                                .add();
                    } else {
                        chart.lbl.attr({
                            text: text
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    }
},
```

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to get all selected points, through `chart.getSelectedpoints()` (same is used in drilldown), and if selections is accumulative (`event.accumulative` in select event will be true) add information about all selected points into your custom label.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xbvmpev5/

**Edit:**

Changed code, because description above is not clear enough:

```
            point: {
                events: {
                    select: function (event) {
                        var text = 'All selected points: <br/>',
                            chart = this.series.chart,
                            otherSelected = chart.getSelectedPoints();
                        if (event.accumulate) {
                            Highcharts.each(otherSelected, function (point) {
                                text += point.category + ': ' + point.y + '<br/>';
                            });
                        }
                        text += this.category + ': ' + this.y + ' (last selected)';
```

Comment: This should be a comment because your example in jsfiddle it's exactly the same as mine and you don't put code to help my issue. Anyway, thanks for visiting

Comment: @FerranBuireu Code is changed, see edit to see what part exactly if description is not clear enough.

Comment: I've changed a bit the code to ensure that in drilldown the X-axis shows the value of the current serie (in animals ships and cows or whatever). It's my fault becuase I changed it in the last minute but your code works perferctly. Answer accepted :)